Drawing iText7 Canvas lines does not always fill page
I have the following code to apply a full page grid to an existing A4 pdf document.
It works fine on pdfs I or others have produced with iText, but when I try to use on a PDF that has been created by me or others using the Win10 "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer driver the resulting grid does not fill the page, it stops short both on the right and bottom of page by a couple of cm.
The fltWidth and fltHeight is approx the same no matter which PDF I input, it is just ones produced with the MS Print to PDF that I have issue with, which are also A4.
pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);
doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
PdfDocument pdfDocData = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourcePDF));

pdfDocData.CopyPagesTo(1, 1, pdfDoc);

iText.Kernel.Colors.Color colorGrey = new DeviceRgb(112, 112, 112);
float flt_02 = 0.2f;

PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetFirstPage();

iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle pageSize = doc.GetPdfDocument().GetFirstPage().GetPageSize();

float fltWidth = pageSize.GetWidth();
float fltHeight = pageSize.GetHeight();

PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

for (int intIndex = 296; intIndex > 0; intIndex--)
{
    float fltLineY = intIndex * 2.83464566929134f;
    canvas.SetStrokeColor(colorGrey);
    canvas.MoveTo(1, fltLineY);
    canvas.LineTo(fltWidth, fltLineY);
    canvas.SetLineWidth(flt_02);
    canvas.ClosePathStroke();
}

for (int intIndex = 1; intIndex < 210; intIndex++)
{
    float fltLineX = intIndex * 2.83464566929134f;
    canvas.SetStrokeColor(colorGrey);
    canvas.MoveTo(fltLineX, 1);
    canvas.LineTo(fltLineX, fltHeight);
    canvas.SetLineWidth(flt_02);
    canvas.ClosePathStroke();
}

doc.Close();
pdfDoc.Close();```



Strictly speaking you create invalid content stream segments: between path definition (move to, line to, ...) and path painting (close path stroke, ...) nothing (except clipping instructions) is allowed, but you put a line width change there. Manny viewers will accept this nonetheless but you may run into trouble in the long run.

Other than that, try new PdfCanvas(page, true) instead of new PdfCanvas(page) to make sure that the old page content is wrapped and no graphics state changes bleed through.

Also you assume that the lower left is the origin of the PDF page coordinate system. That's merely common but not required, the origin may be anywhere. Thus, better use GetLeft, GetRight, GetBottom, and GetTop of the Rectangle pageSize.

Ah, and another hint, A4 allows for small deviations.

thank you both. @mkl  the new PdfCanvas(page, true)  resolved it, if you want to answer with that I will then mark as accepted answer.

@KJ  yes it did look like approx 75% of expected but the values from get width and height were as expected for A4. the 2.834... was 72dpi/25.4mm to convert from mm to dpi for the line drawing. Think I used to use 72/25.4 and had minor issue which the hard code value got round ... but maybe that was related to the canvas non true situation.

When adding content to an existing PDF page, it can be necessary to wrap the existing content into an envelope that stores the original graphics state at the start and restores it at the end. Otherwise any changes applied by the existing content may influence your additions, e.g. by scaling it as in your case, by clipping it, by applying transparency, ...
With iText this can be enforced by using
new PdfCanvas(page, true)

instead of
new PdfCanvas(page)

(Actually the latter variant tries to determines whether adding such an envelope is necessary and sometimes applies it. In your case, though, it errs.)
